# I cant figure out how to parse this xml file with simplexml

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

This is the xml file

```
<diseases>
    <a>
        <name>disease1</name>
        <symptoms>pain</symptoms>
        <treatment></treatment>
    </a> 
    <a>
        <name>disease2</name>
        <symptoms>blood</symptoms>
        <treatment></treatment>
    </a> 
</diseases>
```

And the php to follow. The PHP gets a variable $q which is a disease name and does stristr() to look for the name in any of the child nodes.  Once found I want to be able display all nodes associated with disease name like the symptoms and treatment.

```
` <?php
 $q = $_GET["q"];
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('disease.xml');
  foreach ($xml->a as $disease_and_childnodes) {     
    if (stristr($disease_and_childnodes->children(),$q)) {

        $result = $disease_and_childnodes->xpath('.');

        print_r($result);  //Need to print all the childnodes of this      array instead

         }
    } ?>`
```

So I am using Xpath i found the node that has all the disease info.  If I just print_r I get an array.  How do you display the child nodes one line at a time.  The node is the $result variable now.

Comment: `stristr` works with strings. `$disease_and_childnodes->children()` is at least a collection of objects. Suggestion - is to start reading manuals

Comment: I can return the disease name fine as a string from stristr.  Now I want to use that name and display all other children related that disease name

Comment: `xpath` is your friend here. Look it up, adjust your code, then edit your question if you need support.